# Getting recently replaced fragment from framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm having some trouble acquiring a dynamically placed fragment that is located in a hardcoded framelayout. Here is the code I am trying to figure out.

```
FragmentManager fragmentSwitchManager = getFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction fragmentSwitchTransaction = fragmentSwitchManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentSwitchTransaction.replace(R.id.paletteFrame, new CanvasFragment());
fragmentSwitchTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentSwitchTransaction.commit();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

CanvasFragment canvasFragment = (CanvasFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.paletteFrame);
canvasFragment.updateColor(color);
```

To explain this a bit further, there is a framelayout with the id `paletteFrame` that contains a `PaletteFragment`. I am trying to replace the `PaletteFragment` with a `CanvasFragment`, then call a method associated with that newly replaced `CanvasFragment`.

Now the error I'm getting states that a `PaletteFragment` cannot be cast to a `CanvasFragment`, which means that when I retrieve a fragment from `paletteFrame` using `findFragmentById(R.id.paletteFrame)`, the method retrieves the older `PaletteFragment` that was replaced, not the `CanvasFragment` I replaced it with.

I've been looking around for a while and I can't seem to find how to acquire the most recently added fragment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instane of `CanvasFragment`, and updated it whenever you want, try something like this :

```
    FragmentManager fragmentSwitchManager = getFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentSwitchTransaction = fragmentSwitchManager.beginTransaction();
    CanvasFragment canvasFragment = new CanvasFragment();
    fragmentSwitchTransaction.replace(R.id.paletteFrame,canvasFragment);
    fragmentSwitchTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentSwitchTransaction.commit();

    canvasFragment.updateColor(color);
```